# Which table stores the content type fields?

Tags: nodes, 8, entities, database

I have a content type in drupal 8 and which table stores the content type fields and type in drupal 8 ? `Unlike in drupal 6` (in which there will be tables specifically for content types) like `content_type_contenttypename` its not creating the table and fields . Where will be these fields and data types stored in drupal 8 ??

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Drupal 8:

- Content type = Bundle
- Node = Entity
- Base fields are in one table: `[entity]_field_data`
- Bundle fields are in seperate tables: `[entity]__field_name`

Bundle fields are stored in the same table for all bundles of one entity and can be shared between bundles of the same entity but not with another entity.

Comment: I'm just trying to work out what that `bundle` column in the field tables is actually for, do you know? Given that entity IDs are unique, and a node can only have one bundle, I'm struggling to come up with anything that would make it useful. The description says it's used for when fields are deleted, but that doesn't make sense to me either...

Comment: Bundle is an index key, so this is probably to find content faster. For example if you want to delete a bundle you would otherwise have to go through the complete table.

Comment: Yep, that'll be it. Cheers

Comment: I migrated from d6->d8  , so there are many tables starting **migrate_map_d6_** and **migrate_message_d6_** . Any idea about this ?

Comment: No, never migrated from d6. Ask another question.

Answer (score 2):

Each field values will be stored in a separate table.

For field foo the table name will be node__foo

Comment: So there wont be any table specific to content types ? for each fields in a content type there will be as much tables ?

Comment: Yes. This is the default behavior for bundle (content for for nodes) specific fields in drupal 8

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich IIRC, that changed in D7 when proper field support was introduced in core (rather than CCK).  The D6 method of sometimes using the content type table for field data was fragile, and ended up with broken queries when things changes.   This makes it more stable and predictable.